# How to assign to the nsstring object a NSString with variables?

Tags: objective-c, c

I have the following code:

```
long mins = 02; long secs = 35;
  NSString *allTime = [[NSString alloc]init];
    allTime = @"%i:%i",mins, secs ;
```

But it doesn't work, because when I try to display that nsstring object I got this: %i:%i
Instead of that I want to get: 02:35

How to do that ? 
Thank you!

```
allTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%l/%l", mins, secs];
for(Playlists *thePL in collection)
    {
        NSLog(@"===NEXT PLAYLIST===");
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", thePL.namePL);
        NSLog(@"Quantity of songs: %i", thePL.entries);
        NSLog(@"Total of time: %@",thePL.allTime);
    }
```

TOTAL OF TIME: l

Comment: Please don't edit your questions to add new questions to them — that isn't how Stack Overflow works. If you want to ask a new question, you should do it as a new question. And please take care to ask your questions clearly. You appear to have both an `allTime` local variable and a property `allTime` belonging to the Playlist class. If that isn't actually the case, you'll need to post your real code with context, because it's fiendishly hard to debug heavily abridged code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `stringWithFormat`, see the [**`NSString Class Reference`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

```
allTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d",mins, secs];
```

Comment: Not equivalent to the OP's code - different release rules (sans ARC).

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Not really. There are no "release rules" for the expression `@"%i:%i",mins, secs` — it yields a long, not an object. If that were somehow a valid way to create a string, though, it would almost certainly be equivalent to `stringWithFormat:`, not `alloc`+`initWithFormat:`, as it does not contain any of the magic words that confer ownership.

Comment: Well, there's a compilation error in the OP's code. Modulo that, there's a memory leak. Modulo that, I guess he wants a non-autoreleased string :) Again, we don't know if ARC is enabled.

Comment: For a new problem with new code, accept an answer to this question and create a new question. That's how SO works - this is not a forum.

Answer (score 4):

```
long mins = 02;
long secs = 35;   
NSString *allTime = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%d:%d", mins, secs];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
NSString *allTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d",mins, secs];
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should read the calss reference of NSString.
second, you should use this code:

```
 NSString *allTime = [stringWithFormat:@"%d,:%d", mins, secs]
```

you can also to alloc the string and then initialize it by this way:

```
NSString *allTime = [[Nsstring alloc] init];
allTime = [NSString stringWithForat:@"%d:%d", mins, secs];
```

although, the best, the short and the better way is the first one. 
hope this help...