# How to get NSString with variables?

Tags: objective-c, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign to the nsstring object a NSString with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420100/how-to-assign-to-the-nsstring-object-a-nsstring-with-variables)

When I try to display that nsstring object, I get this:

> TOTAL OF TIME: l

Instead of that I want to get: 02:35

How to do that ? Thank you!

```
allTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%l/%l", mins, secs];
for(Playlists *thePL in collection)
    {
        NSLog(@"===NEXT PLAYLIST===");
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", thePL.namePL);
        NSLog(@"Quantity of songs: %i", thePL.entries);
        NSLog(@"Total of time: %@",thePL.allTime);
    }
```

Comment: repost of [How to assign to the nsstring object a NSString with variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420100/how-to-assign-to-the-nsstring-object-a-nsstring-with-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `mins` and `secs` are integers:

```
allTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i", mins, secs];
```

If you want more information search the [String format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the format specifier %ld for specifying long..

Like this..

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld/%ld", mins, secs];
```